# How to add text to a ProgressBar?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-progressbar

So this is my `ProgressBar`. Is it possible to write text "in" the bar?

```
<ProgressBar
    android:id="@+id/kcal"
    style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@id/makros"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
    android:background="@android:color/holo_green_light" />
```

Comment: If you want to have a ProgressBar with text, why don't you try ProgressDialog?

Comment: Do you want it in a dialog?? If yes than you should use ```ProgressDialog.show(activity, title, message, true, isCancellable, cancelListener);```. If you want it in a layout than you will need to add a separate textview